# How to run my java swing desktop application on mobile?

Tags: java, android, swing, headless

I was wondering if I could run a desktop application that uses swing libraries on a mobile device. I know it's a simple question yet interesting.

**Attempt**

I used `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless","true");`, but it seems to do nothing and throws a HeadlessException, issue also presented before using the method. Moreover, I would prefer not using this method because it limits the swing library features.

**Specs**

- Device **:** Samsung J8
- OS **:** Android Pie 9
- Coding app **:** DCoder
- Plugged keyboard **:** Yes
- Plugged mouse **:** No
- Screen **:** Mobile's screen

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:208)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:548)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:388)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
        at Test.<init>(source.java:5)
        at Test.main(source.java:13)
```

**Code**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class Test extends JFrame {

  public Test () {
    setSize(180,100);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  public static void main (String [] args) {
    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless","true");
    Test test = new Test();
  }
}
```

Thanks for taking your time to read my question, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if I could run a desktop application that uses swing libraries on a mobile device

Not on an Android device, sorry.

Comment: Ain't there a kinda of elumator that can do that stuff, I'm using DCoder to run my java files?

Comment: @TundraSpirit: "Ain't there a kinda of elumator that can do that stuff" -- not that I am aware of, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

[**EDIT**]: You can also use [Replit](https://replit.com) and it's Java Swing template.

You can try copying your app into [Termux](https://termux.com)
And use VNC server or Termux-X11 to view your application.

To setup Termux, first go to their [website](https://termux.com)
And download it from there.

Then once that is done, run the .apk file you downloaded. (Do not use the one in the Google Play Store because it no longer works.)

Once you install the App, open the app and wait for it to extract the rootfs. Once it is extracted, type

"termux-setup-storage"  (StackOverflow doesn't let me use
the snippet editor on touchscreen.)  To setup the storage, which isn't nessecary but useful to have.

After that type "pkg update", pkg is simply apt but in termux. You can also use "apt update" like in Debian.

After that type "pkg install openjdk-17-jdk" to install OpenJDK 17 on Termux.

Then you can use built-in text editors such as Nano, or copy your Class files or Source files into your ~/storage directory.

To compile a Java source file, run: "javac "
To run a Class file, run:
"java "